# How to get image from facebook and uploading on server?

Tags: android

> i want to get image from facebook and upload on the server but i am unable to get the image...how can i do this?`

```
try {
                                    String imageURL="http://graph.facebook.com/"+ userFbId+ "/picture?type=large";
                                    URL image_value = new URL(imageURL);

                                    try {
                                        bm270 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    //userPicture.setImageBitmap(bm270);
                                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

Comment: Use Glide or Passico or Universal-Image-Loader to help you to load image.

Comment: i don't have any idea about this...can u please explain this through code?

Comment: i think no one has the answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

[image: add library]

[image: download image]

1.Add `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'` in you `build.gradle`.

2.Download image:

```
String imageURL="http://i9.baidu.com/it/u=4155509453,935829176&fm=96&s=CF86AC45FACB2F6C1C9CB5000300E093";
Glide.with(ActivityA.this).load(imageURL).downloadOnly(new SimpleTarget<File>() {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(File resource, GlideAnimation<? super File> glideAnimation) {
        Glide.with(ActivityA.this).load(resource).into(m);
    }
});
```